# Lambda expression resetting value of variable in a object when sorting

Tags: python, lambda

I am trying to sort a list of objects in python via a value of a variable on the object. I am using the following lambda expression to do this.

```
p = []

for i in range(10):
     p.append(Obj())

p.sort(key=lambda l: l.get_chi_2(), reverse=False)

for i in range(10):
    print(p[i].get_chi_2())
```

However, when this is run for some reason it resets the value of this variable back to its original value of 0. I checkd with a debugger and it has its correct value until after this line is run. The relevant object functions are below

```
class Obj:
    chi_2 = -1

    def __init__(self):
        self.chi_2 = randint(0, 10)

    def get_chi_2(self):
        return self.chi_2

    def set_chi_2(self, chi_2):
        self.chi_2 = chi_2
```

I am unsure of what is causing this, as from my understanding of the lambda expression it should just be sorting by what the get function returns. Calling the get function on its own correctly returns the desired variable and does not reset it. I even tried just accessing the variable directly and got the same result. But I am pretty sure it is that sort line that is causing the issue.

Comment: Please show a [mre]. Currently the question is lacking a complete class definition as well as the definition of `p`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 p is a list of the object as defined below, the relevant parts of the class are there to reproduce it.

Comment: Yes, please show that, so that we can copy and paste the code and see the problem.

Comment: @mkrieger1 i added a for loop to generate a list of 10 of the objects and the __init__ to randomly generate a value for the variable

Comment: How do you get to the conclusion that the variable is reset to 0? The code doesn't produce any output.

Comment: @mkrieger1 as specified in the orginal question, both with a debugger and print statements.

Comment: Please show that, as part of the minimal **reproducible** example.

Comment: how can i show a debugger?

Comment: Add some print statements to the code (**in the question**, not just on your computer) which demonstrate that some values are 0 when they should not be.

Comment: Also please take a minute to read (again) the page I've linked to above. Now the code gives an error "'list' object has no attribute 'get_chi_2'".

Comment: `chi_2` is a CLASS VARIABLE

Comment: Now I get "1
1
3
3
3
7
7
8
9
10". No values were reset to 0.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i understand being able to reproduce the code, i gave reproduceable code, not includeing print statements seriously, when i stated i used a debugger for the most part

Comment: @Sean *no*, the code you provided **does not reproduce the problem you described**. That's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you want:

```
p.sort(key=lambda l: l.chi_2, reverse=False)
```

```
from random import randint
class Obj:
        chi_2 = -1

        def __init__(self):
            self.chi_2 = randint(0, 10)

        def get_chi_2(self):
            return self.chi_2

        def set_chi_2(self, chi_2):
            self.chi_2 = chi_2

p = [Obj() for i in range(10)]
print([i.chi_2 for i in p])

p.sort(key=lambda l: l.chi_2, reverse=False)
print([i.chi_2 for i in p])
```

output:

```
[5, 10, 0, 10, 0, 9, 8, 3, 1, 2]
[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10, 10]
```

after toying with it after the update

```
print([i.get_chi_2() for i in p])

print([i.chi_2 for i in p])

p.sort(key=lambda l: l.get_chi_2(), reverse=False)

print([i.chi_2 for i in p])
```

i am still getting consistent results, i think we can dismiss this as typo?

```
[2, 9, 0, 5, 6, 10, 9, 7, 3, 5]
[2, 9, 0, 5, 6, 10, 9, 7, 3, 5]
[0, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 9, 9, 10]
```

Comment: as specified in the original question i tried both and both cause the value to be reset to 0, which is the default value set in the __init__

Comment: thats not true though, ill edit to show you my output when ran

Comment: ill try that agin in a second, any idea how come that function would not get the same result as using the varaible directly?

Comment: by returning it might reference it weirdy? ill see if i can replicate it :)

Comment: i tried this again and referenceing it directly seems to have worked now, tho i am still confused why referecing it through a method apears to cause an issue

Comment: @Sean it doesn't. As demonstrated above and by the very code you provide. There is obviously something else going on, which is why you have to provide a [mcve]

Comment: as edited i get the same results even with a getter, but as juanpa said you probably shouldn't use getters it's easier to just directly reference either way. If you do find out what went wrong I would love to see what went wrong. Still, thank you for asking, and happy coding :)